# Display VAT price on products

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have added a 20% vat on my products. This is added during checkout. How can I add it to the display price when you view the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the [VAT](http://drupal.org/project/uc_vat) module. Ubercart's prices aren't flexible enough to adjust the display price based on the VAT. You should probably enter the prices for each product including the VAT and adjust your uc_vat so the sell price is inclusive.